# Warning "Prop `src` did not match" in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render an image depending on the device of the user.

This is my image component:

```
interface Props {
  image: string;
  alt: string;
  device: string;
}

export const Image = (props: Props) => {
  const { image, alt, device } = props;
  const imgPreset = getPreset(device);
  return (
    <img
        src={image + '?' + imgPreset}
        alt={alt}
    />
  );
};
```

getPreset() is only returning some parameters (e.g. quality, width, height) depending on the device

I'm now getting this warning when I'm on a mobile device:

```
Warning: Prop `src` did not match. Server: "https://someImgUrl?&qlt=60,1..." Client: "https://someImgUrl?&qlt=40,1..."
```

I know that I get this error because the code is running on server-side and on client-side with different 'results', but I don't know how to fix it.

For device detection I'm using the module [react-device-detect](https://github.com/duskload/react-device-detect)

```
import { isMobile } from 'react-device-detect';
const device = isMobile ? "mobile" : "desktop"
```

I'm doing the device detection on client-side, that's why i'm getting the error. I also tried to implement it on server-side but there it is always returning "desktop" even on mobile devices.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `react-device-detect` supports SSR
https://github.com/duskload/react-device-detect/blob/master/docs/api.md#utils--ssr

I think you should get context about the device in the serverside.

Comment: Ah, I didn't saw that before. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [@Bad Dobby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6661359/bad-dobby) react-device-detect supports SSR:

https://github.com/duskload/react-device-detect/blob/master/docs/api.md#utils--ssr

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const userAgent = context.req.headers['user-agent'] ? context.req.headers['user-agent'] : ""
  const { isMobile } = getSelectorsByUserAgent(userAgent)
  const device = isMobile ? "mobile" : "desktop"

  ...
};
```